# Select from Database where and like

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, row

I am trying to show results from a DB where a search criteria can be matched in various columns.

Here is my current code

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' ")
       or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
```

How do i say select all from products where prodname AND catagory AND prodID are like $name?

Thanks

Comment: or die('Error: Line 519  OMG HARDCODED LINE NUMBER IN a ERROR MESSAGE ??? if you place more code above your code would really give wrong debugging information... you should use constant LINE there see http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE
 `prodname` LIKE '$name%' 
 and `catagory`  LIKE '$name%' 
 and `prodID`   LIKE '$name%' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '$name%' AND `category` LIKE '$name%' AND `prodID` LIKE '$name%' ") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something pretty straight forward because you are asking the question and the answer is lying in the question itself.
your query is not correct but it will impact on the column in the where clause.
but you have to find the result on the basis of the other two columns that are 'catagory' and 'prodID'
so what you have to do is to include the other two columns just same as that you'd used in the previous query.
 means you have to include the following in the query in the where clause:

```
and `catagory`  LIKE '$name%' 
 and `prodID`   LIKE '$name%' ;
```

hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks, however when i replace my current coding with this, the search doesn't work at all?

Comment: how can it work man. you have applied so many filters on three fields and you are applying it with an AND clause between them.
means you are turning very rude on your database by employing this query.